# Google Play In-app Billing - how to do "signature verification tasks on a server"?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

Im looking at security and bets practices when doing [In app billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html) and I cannot figure out how would I implement "signature verification on a server"...

Does anyone have an example of this? What security concerns would it solve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server-side verification of Google Play In-app billing version 3 purchase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067180/server-side-verification-of-google-play-in-app-billing-version-3-purchase)