# Looking for platform for subscription in app purchase verification on server side for Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Im trying to implement server side verification for subscription in app purchase. What platform is better to use for that purpose. I have found end points in google cloud platform but its deprecated. Im using firebase for this project maybe there Is a solution for both of them.

I have found that question on stack and it helped me the high level overview for this process but still not enough information how to start and where i can start.
[How to verify purchase for android app in server side (google play in app billing v3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850864/how-to-verify-purchase-for-android-app-in-server-side-google-play-in-app-billin)

Answer (score 0):

When Google recommends server-side verification, it means verifying the purchase signature on an external server that could be hosted on simple web hosting. https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices

Here is an example of how to implement :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48645216/7690376

Comment: thank u. Does google provide any server where i can put that code?

Comment: As far as I know the answer is no.

Comment: Subscription Based Billing is not possible without server implementation??

Comment: You don't need a server, but your app will be more protected against fraud if you have one. To verify the signature and for other verifications such as checking non-repeated tokens, with a web hosting and some PHP knowledge you have enough.